# MS SQL 2008 express connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have VDS hosting with MS SQL Server 2008 express. Some users should be connected simultaneously. What quantity of simultaneous connections supports MS SQL Server 2008 Express?

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a limit on the number of concurrent connections.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=SQL.100).aspx, SQL Server 2008 handles 32,767 user connections.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 Express has following limitations:

- 1 CPU socket
- 1 GB memory
- 4 GB of user data per database

there is no another limitations.